# Swift: How to handle the Chats class

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My question is very basic as I am about to learn swift at the moment.

I have written this function

```
    func checkIfChatExistsLocal(username:String) -> Bool {

    var result = [Chats]()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Chats")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    let userPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = '\(username)'")
    fetchRequest.predicate = userPredicate
    result = try! self.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Chats]

    if result == nil {
        print("nil")
        return false
    } else {
        let rresult = result[0].username
        return true
    }
    print("Result \(rresult)")

}
```

the if part is wrong and I basically know why (because `result` is of type `[Chats]`) and that is the point where my understanding problem comes up:

How do I handle `result`?

with `result = .... as! [Chats]`  I declare `result` as an Array (?) of type `Chats` which is class (?) - so an Array of classes?

Chats.swift - by the way - is:

```
@objc(Chats)
 class Chats: NSManagedObject {

     // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

 }
```

with

```
extension Chats {

     @NSManaged var username: String?

}
```

So first (to help me out) how can I fix my code to get it running?

And second:
What part of "Learning Swift" should I consolidate to handle `result = .... as! [Chats]`?

Comment: It's an array of `Chats` instances. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve, and any compile / runtime errors you get.

Comment: I want to check if a username is stored in CoreData entity "Chats" if yes -> return true and if not -> return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stated requirement you shouldn't be using `executeFetchRequest`, you should instead use `countForFetchRequest`. Now you don't need to worry about an array of items at all, you just check the number and use that to decide what to return:

```
return (count > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment - that is a good idea and the solution of what I wrote - but I want to use the username too